# Live search using angular js for php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a live search method (showing results while typing instantly) for my web application. I don't know how to implement the code to HTML correctly.

This is my script file in index.php:

```
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        PATH = 'cari.php';
        var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
        //live search controller for welcome view and welcome controller
        app.controller('SearchController', function($scope, $http){
            $scope.url = 'cari.php'; // the get request page
            $scope.search = function (){
                //create the http post request
                //the data holds the search key
                //the request is a json request
                $http.post($scope.url,
                {"data" : $scope.keywords}
                        ).success(function (data, status){
                            $scope.status = status;
                            $scope.data = data;
                            $scope.result = data;
                        }).error(function (data, status){
                            $scope.data = data || "Request Failed";
                            $scope.status = status;
                        });
            };
        });
    </script>
```

This is my cari.php file to search database using php:

```
<?php
    require_once './koneksidb.php';
    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $objData = json_decode($data);
    $key =  $objData->data;
    if(!empty($key)){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM nim_finder WHERE nama LIKE '%$key%' or   nim_tpb LIKE '%$key%' or nim_prodi LIKE '%$key%'";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
        $output = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $output[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
?>
```

This is kondeksidb.php file:

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("hostiscorrect", "usernameiscorrect", "passwordiscorrect", "dbcorrectbelievemeivetried") or die'Error connecting to database: ');
```

This is my index.php I have been working on (The same file as the script located, but without anything unrelated):

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="SearchController">
<form>
 <div class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="input-group">
   <input ng-model="keywords" name="mhs" id="txtkey" class="form-control" placeholder="Cari nama atau NIM" aria-describedby="ddlsearch" type="text">
   <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button ng-click="search()" id="btn-search" class="btn btn-info" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i></button>
   </span>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
<table id="hasil" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
<thead><tr><th>NIM Prodi</th><th>NIM TPB</th><th>Nama</th><th>Angkatan</th><th>Jurusan</th><th>Email</th></tr></thead>
<tfoot><tr><th>NIM Prodi</th><th>NIM TPB</th><th>Nama</th><th>Angkatan</th><th>Jurusan</th><th>Email</th></tr></tfoot>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="x in result"><td>{{x.nim_prodi}}</td><td>{{x.nim_tpb}}</td><td>{{x.nama}}</td><td>{{x.angkatan}}</td><td>{{x.prodi}}</td><td>{{x.email}}</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

This is a picture of my database file:
[nim_finder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjjEy.jpg)

I have tried:

- change ng-model from "keywords" to "data"
- change directory definition (adding "/")
- database connection sure is correct
- I dont understand how the script could show the result more effective

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: nothing, it just didn't work. Do you any fault on my code?

Comment: update, the status says 500, does it mean internal server error? if so, which mistake do I have?

Answer (score 0):

You can just refer  below link

http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/php-angularjs-crud-with-search-and-pagination-example-from-scratchexample.html

Comment: It's pretty different from my code, I couldn't implement it